# MongoTemplate return userId null within SpringBoot project

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I work with spring boot and mongoDB, i try to make a complex request with MongoTemplate to get all portfolios with no empty projects but for all results i receive userId null and i don't understand where i'm wrong. I'm newby on springboot, any help will be appreciate.

When i execute a simple request like List portfolios = portfolioRepository.findAll(); the userId is not null

This is my code:

**PortfolioRepositoryImpl (with MongoTemplate)**

```
public List<Portfolio> getPortfolioWithNoEmptyProjects() {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("projects").exists(true).ne(new ArrayList<>()));
    query.fields().elemMatch("projects", Criteria.where("online").is(true));
    // query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "created"));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, Portfolio.class);
  }
```

**Portfolio Document**

```
@Document
public class Portfolio {

    @Id
    @Getter
    private String id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotBlank(message = "media.user.id.not.be.null.or.empty")
    private String userId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NotNull(message = "portfolio.projects.not.be.null")
    private ArrayList<Project> projects;

    public Portfolio() {
        this.projects = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

**The structure of the document**

[image]

**The result**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem just need to include expected fields as following

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("user");
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("projects").exists(true).ne(new ArrayList<>()));
query.fields().elemMatch("projects", Criteria.where("online").is(true));
return mongoTemplate.find(query, Portfolio.class);
```